# How to read a file from the disk if less than X days old, if older, refetch the html file

Tags: perl, caching, http-headers

I wish to read an html file off of the internet and cache it. Then when I go back, because I'm debugging, I don't want to hammer the servers with the numerous requests I'll need. I don't want to get my IP banned for slamming the server over and over again just because I'm debugging. So my code needs to look something like:

```
if ((file > days_old) || !(file exists))
   fetch html file from internet
   save file to disk
else
   read it from the disk
```

Because there will be multiple files, I'll need to include a variable name in the file name so the file is unique and I can easily look it up again.

I just learned Perl this semester and we only learned the basics & a bit of regex, once I get this I should be mostly fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an existing module:

- [Cache::Cache](http://perl-cache.sf.net/)
- [HTTP::Cache::Transparent](http://p3rl.org/HTTP%3a%3aCache%3a%3aTransparent)

If you really want to implement your own, you'll want to look at the [`If-Modified-Since` and `ETag` HTTP headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) to determine when to re-fetch a file, rather than an arbitrary `days_old` number you suck out of your thumb. You will also have to generate a unique filename, preferably with a hash function, while retaining the original URL to cater for hash collisions.

Comment: I ended up using the second option and set the No Update key to 2 days and turned verbose on to see what was going on. Worked fantastic TY!